# What is the function of the `text_target` parameter in Huggingface's `AutoTokenizer`?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I'm following the guide here: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.28.1/tasks/summarization
There is one line in the guide like this:

```
labels = tokenizer(text_target=examples["summary"], max_length=128, truncation=True)
```

I don't understand the function of the `text_target` parameter.

I tried the following code and the last two lines gave exactly the same results.

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('t5-small')
text = "Weiter Verhandlung in Syrien."
tokenizer(text_target=text, max_length=128, truncation=True)
tokenizer(text, max_length=128, truncation=True)
```

The docs just say `text_target (str, List[str], List[List[str]], optional) — The sequence or batch of sequences to be encoded as target texts.` I don't really understand. Is there some situations when setting  `text_target` will give you a different result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes it is necessary to look at the [code](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/04ab5605fbb4ef207b10bf2772d88c53fc242e83/src/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py#L2545):

```py
if text is None and text_target is None:
    raise ValueError("You need to specify either `text` or `text_target`.")
if text is not None:
    # The context manager will send the inputs as normal texts and not text_target, but we shouldn't change the
    # input mode in this case.
    if not self._in_target_context_manager:
        self._switch_to_input_mode()
    encodings = self._call_one(text=text, text_pair=text_pair, **all_kwargs)
if text_target is not None:
    self._switch_to_target_mode()
    target_encodings = self._call_one(text=text_target, text_pair=text_pair_target, **all_kwargs)
# Leave back tokenizer in input mode
self._switch_to_input_mode()

if text_target is None:
    return encodings
elif text is None:
    return target_encodings
else:
    encodings["labels"] = target_encodings["input_ids"]
    return encodings
```

As you can see in the above snippet, both `text` and `text_target` are passed to `self._call_one()` to encode them (note that `text_target` is passed as the `text` parameter). That means the encoding of the same string as `text` or `text_target` will be identical as long as `_switch_to_target_mode()` doesn't do anything special.

The conditions at the end of the function answer your question:

1. When you only provide `text` you will retrieve the encoding of it.
2. When you only provide `text_target` you will retrieve the encoding of it.
3. When you provide `text` and `text_target` you will retrieve the encoding of `text` and the token ids of `text_target` as the value of the `labels` key.

To be honest, I think the implementation is a bit unintuitive. I would expect that passing the `text_target` would return an object that only contains the `labels` key. I assume that they wanted to keep their output objects and the respective documentation simple and therefore went for this implementation. Or there is a model where it actually makes sense that I am unaware of.

Answer (score 1):

```
dataset_dict  = df_dataset.train_test_split(test_size=0.2, shuffle=False)
train_dataset = dataset_dict["train"]

def preprocess_text_classification(example: dict[str, str | int]) -> BatchEncoding:
    print(example)
    encoded_example           = tokenizer(example["sentence"], max_length=512)
    encoded_example["labels"] = example["label"]
    return encoded_example

encoded_train_dataset = train_dataset.map(
    preprocess_text_classification,
    remove_columns=train_dataset.column_names,
)
```

> `ValueError: You need to specify either "text" or "text_target".`

error happens.

Reason is that `example` variable is sometimes None.

> print(example)
> ...
> {'sentence': 'gaming', 'label': 1}
> {'sentence': None, 'label': 0}
> {'sentence': 'gambling', 'label': 0}
> ...

So, the error has gone after filling missing value for avoiding None value.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this was the issue in my case, thank you! Error message could be better.